# is there a merged iterator implementation?

Tags: java, iterator

Is there an Iterator implementation that merges multiple iterators?

```
class MergedIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
{
     MergedIterator(Iterator<T>... iters)
     ....
}
```

And the next method should move on to `iters[1]` when `!iters[0].hasNext()` etc

Comment: I think you'd be better off with Iterables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd call that a ConcatenatedIterator myself - a MergedIterator should merge the results of several iterators e.g. based on sorting

Naming aside, I'm sure there'll be an implementation in a 3rd party library somewhere. Just off to check [Google collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)...

EDIT: Bingo - [Iterators.concat](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#concat(java.util.Iterator...))

Comment: Or SequenceIterator, like SequenceInputStream.

Answer (score 3):

Commons Collections [IteratorChain](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/IteratorChain.html)

Answer (score 1):

there's one in groovy: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Iterator+Tricks - you can probably roll one up like this with a few more lines of code.